# Italic text is cut off by next run's background. How can I highlight such text?

Tags: wpf

I want to highlight a word in the TextBlock. The word consists of several runs with different formatting applied. The italic text is cut off by next run's background.

## Highlight with Background

I've made the highlight semitransparent so you can see what is cut off.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Before " />
    <Span Background="#80ffff00">
        <Run FontStyle="Italic" Text="T" /><Run Text="ext" />
    </Span>
    <Run Text=" after." />
</TextBlock>
```

[image: "cut off with background" screenshot]

## Highlight with TextDecoration

The closest workaround I have found is to highlight it with TextDecorations. But in that case I have to set semitransparent highlight and the text is no longer black as it is covered by the text decoration.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Before " />
    <Span>
        <Span.TextDecorations>
            <TextDecoration Location="Strikethrough" 
                            PenThicknessUnit="FontRenderingEmSize" 
                            PenOffset="0.5">
                <TextDecoration.Pen>
                    <Pen Brush="#80ffff00" Thickness="1" />
                </TextDecoration.Pen>
            </TextDecoration>
        </Span.TextDecorations>
        <Run FontStyle="Italic" Text="T" /><Run Text="ext" />
    </Span>
    <Run Text=" after." />
</TextBlock>
```

[image: "text is no longer black" screenshot]

Could you please give any idea how can I highlight such text?

Comment: It tried a FlowDocument with RichTextBox and same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was noticing a similar cutoff of italicized text in my application. I fixed it by using the style below to automatically give all Run controls a transparent background. I don't know if this will fix your problem, but it fixed mine.

Caution: This might have unintended consequences by giving all Run controls a transparent background - and I'm a newbie at WPF.

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Run}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    </Style>
```

Here's without the style - notice that the word *fall* is italicized, but the comma isn't, so the *l* is being cutoff:
[italicized word *fall* with *l* cut off by non-italicized comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVHbN.png)

Here's with the style - notice that the comma no longer cuts off the *l*:
[italicized word *fall* with *l* not cut off by non-italicized comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQcrv.png)

Comment: I need the text to be highlighed. And when I give all Run elements a transparent background the span's background becomes transparent too.